# unset all environment variables starting with a leading string while in a script (without closing or restarting bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to:

> unset myvarname*

where myvarname is a string and * is... well, you got it.

Tried

> env | grep string | unset

but doesn't work.

I'm into a script and I don't want to start a new shell so no env -i or source something or leaving the reentering the shell

Please help a poor noob

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the Bash shell, the `${!prefix@}` parameter expansion generates all variables that start with `prefix`.

> `${!prefix@}`
>                 Expands to the names of variables  whose names begin with prefix
>                 [...] When @ is used and the expansion  appears within  double
>                 quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

This list can then be passed to `unset`:

```
unset "${!myvarname@}"
```

Answer (score 14):

If it's the `bash` shell, do:

```
unset $(compgen -v myvarname)
```

For example, show all variables in my current environment beginning with the letter '*S*':

```
unset $(compgen -v  S)
```

Output:

```
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN
SCREEN_NO
SECONDS
SESSION
SESSIONTYPE
SHELL
SHELLOPTS
SHLVL
SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

If it's a *POSIX* shell, try something more generic:

```
unset $(env | sed -n 's/^\(S.*\)=.*/\1/p')
```

Or if *GNU* `grep` is available:

```
unset $(env | grep -o '^S[^=]*')
```

Comment: `-v` is for all shell variables (exported as well as local). `-e` is for exported/environment variables, so that's probably what the OP wants since they are using `env`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151118/understand-compgen-builtin-command/151120#151120

Comment: @wisbucky, This works: `nn1=foo nn2=bar nn3=baz ; compgen -v n`, but this does not `nn1=foo nn2=bar nn3=baz ; compgen -e n`.  Please elaborate if there's more to it...

Answer (score 9):

Try this -

```
unset $(env | grep string |awk -F'=' '{print $1}')
```

Let say I have environment variable like -

```
printenv
string1=hello
string2=vipin
```

and when you will search with string grep will fetch both environment and fetch the name of environment variable and pass to unset command.

Comment: `env | awk -F= '{print $1}'` can give false-positive results when env values are multi-line strings. `compgen -e` returns only the env names