# How to clear all env variables

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

If I do:

```
$ env
```

It will print out all the environmental variables. Is there a way to delete all variables without looping through them individually in bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but be careful what you wish for:

```
$ unset $(env | awk -F= '{print $1}') && env
bash: env: No such file or directory
```

The 2nd call to **env**(1) fails because `PATH` has been deleted.

An alternative might be `exec -c`, to execute some command from a subshell with no environment.  But a better route, if you're worried about too much stuff in the environment, is to look back and see where that excess stuff came from, and clear it up there.

Comment: `env | awk -F= '{print $1}'` can give false-positive results when env values are multi-line strings. `compgen -e` returns only the env names. see also [unset all environment variables starting with a leading string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122201/unset-all-environment-variables-starting-with-a-leading-string-while-in-a-script/43126805#43126805)